# C#-like case when in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I come from a C# background and one really nice thing they offer is a way to add conditionals to a switch statement

```cs
switch(type)
{
    case "edit":
        // do something...
        break;
    case "delete" when user.isAdmin:
        // do something...
        break;
}
```

I'm curious if Kotlin has such an ability with their equivalent when? I'm not seeing that it's possible but I'm also still getting the hang of Kotlin so maybe there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, guess I should have just asked Android studio XD

for those wondering, heres how:

```kotlin
when {
    type == "edit" -> {
        // do sometihng...
    }
    type == "delete" && user.isAdmin -> {
        // do sometihng...
    }
}
```

hope this helped someone else.

Comment: Semantically, this is the same thing as a sequence of `if` statements (i.e. `O(n)` for `n`-many conditions), whereas as C#'s `switch`  and Kotlin's `when` (when used with constant `case` values) _may_ be compiled to a jump-table for `O(1)` runtime. Just FYI OFC YMMV ETC.

Comment: this just looks better than an if tree

Comment: Right, but when it's `O(1)` vs `O(n)`, then performance should trump aesthetics, imo.

Comment: I don't see this causing any performance issues, and any it *may* cause is minimal